# Combine Expressions instead of using multiple queries in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have following generic queryable (which may already have selections applied):

```
IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = DBSet<TEntity>.AsQueryable();
```

Then there is the `Provider` class that looks like this:

```
public class Provider<TEntity>
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Condition { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

The `Condition` could be defined per instance in the following fashion:

```
Condition = entity => entity.Id == 3;
```

Now I want to select all `Provider` instances which have a `Condition` that is met at least by one entity of the `DBSet`:

```
List<Provider> providers = [...];
var matchingProviders = providers.Where(provider => queryable.Any(provider.Condition))
```

The problem with this: I'm starting a query for each `Provider` instance in the list. I'd rather use a single query to achieve the same result. This topic is especially important because of questionable performance. How can I achieve the same results with a single query and improve performance using `Linq` statements or `Expression Trees`?

Comment: This depends greatly on what `provider.Condition` is.  If that can be translated by EF into a sql query, then you can gather all conditions and use them within a single query--the reverse of `queryable.Any(provider.Condition)`.

Comment: All conditions I want to use can be translated into SQL queries by EF

Comment: **This depends greatly on what `provider.Condition` is**. If that can be translated by EF into a sql query, then you can gather all conditions and use them within a single query--the reverse of `queryable.Any(provider.Condition)`.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting challenge. The only way I see is to build dynamically `UNION ALL` query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 0 FROM Table WHERE Condition[0]
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Table WHERE Condition[1]
...
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 N-1 FROM Table WHERE Condition[N-1]
```

and then use the returned numbers as index to get the matching providers.

Something like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
var indexQuery = providers
    .Select((provider, index) => queryable
        .Where(provider.Condition)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(Expression.Constant(index), parameter)))
    .Aggregate(Queryable.Concat);

var indexes = indexQuery.ToList();
var matchingProviders = indexes.Select(index => providers[index]);
```

Note that I could have built the query without using `Expression` class by replacing the above `Select` with

```
.Select(_ => index)
```

but that would introduce unnecessary SQL query parameter for each index.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same thing though? There's still multiple queries, only this time they are being UNIONed together.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah. Technically it's a single SQL query, but there is no guarantee it will be more efficient than executing multiple queries. Although theoretically the SQL optimizer might create an efficient execution plan, so this at least is giving it that chance :)

Comment: I find this very interresting and I had to test it out immediately, The code technically works and I upvoted your answer as well. Sadly it still seems to be slower according to some benchmarks I'm using: `Old Method: 148ms` < `IndexQuery ToList: 395ms` when using about 7 Providers with 2000 entries.

Comment: @IvanStoev By the way, I found that you can simplify the inner `Select` statement by replacing `Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(Expression.Constant(index), parameter)))` with `Select(entity => index))`

Comment: @SebastianKrogull I mentioned that at the end of the answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev My bad, didn't get it at first.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another (crazy) idea that came in my mind. Please note that similar to my previous answer, it doesn't guarantee better performance (in fact it could be worse). It just presents a way to do what you are asking with a single SQL query.

Here we are going to create a query that returns a single `string` with length N consisting of '0' and '1' characters with '1' denoting a match (something like string bit array). The query will use my favorite *group by constant* technique to build dynamically something like this:

```
var matchInfo = queryable
    .GroupBy(e => 1)
    .Select(g =>
        (g.Max(Condition[0] ? "1" : "0")) +
        (g.Max(Condition[1] ? "1" : "0")) +
            ...
        (g.Max(Condition[N-1] ? "1" : "0")))
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

And here is the code:

```
var group = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<int, TEntity>), "g");

var concatArgs = providers.Select(provider => Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Max", new[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(string) },
        group, Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Condition(
                provider.Condition.Body, Expression.Constant("1"), Expression.Constant("0")),
            provider.Condition.Parameters)));

var concatCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string[]) }),
    Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), concatArgs));

var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<int, TEntity>, string>>(concatCall, group);

var matchInfo = queryable
    .GroupBy(e => 1)
    .Select(selector)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";

var matchingProviders = matchInfo.Zip(providers,
    (match, provider) => match == '1' ? provider : null)
    .Where(provider => provider != null)
    .ToList();
```

Enjoy:)

**P.S.** In my opinion, this query will run with constant speed (regarding number and type of the conditions, i.e. can be considered **O(N)** in the best, worst and average cases, where **N** is the number of the records in the table) because the database has to perform always a full table scan. Still it will be interesting to know what's the actual performance, but most likely doing something like this just doesn't worth the efforts.

**Update:** Regarding the bounty and the updated requirement:

> Find a fast query that **only reads a record of the table once** and **ends the query if already all conditions are met**

There is no standard SQL construct (not even speaking about LINQ query translation) that satisfies both conditions. The constructs that allow early end like `EXISTS` can be used for a single condition, thus when executed for multiple conditions will violate the first rule of reading the table record only once. While the constructs that use aggregates like in this answer satisfy the first rule, but in order to produce the aggregate value they have to read all the records, thus cannot exit earlier.

Shortly, there is no query that can satisfy both requirements. What about the *fast* part, it really depends of the size of the data and the number and type of the conditions, table indexes etc., so again there is simply no "best" general solution for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026155/1171404) by @Ivan I created an expression that is slightly faster in some cases.

It uses `Any` instead of `Max` to get the desired results.

```
var group = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<int, TEntity>), "g");

var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters()
    .Count() == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity));

var concatArgs = Providers.Select(provider => 
    Expression.Call(anyMethod, group, 
    Expression.Lambda(provider.Condition.Body, provider.Condition.Parameters)));

var convertExpression = concatArgs.Select(concat =>
    Expression.Condition(concat, Expression.Constant("1"), Expression.Constant("0")));

var concatCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string[]) }),
    Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), convertExpression));

var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<int, TEntity>, string>>(concatCall, group);

var matchInfo = queryable
    .GroupBy(e => 1)
    .Select(selector)
    .First();

var MatchingProviders = matchInfo.Zip(Providers,
    (match, provider) => match == '1' ? provider : null)
    .Where(provider => provider != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice that you found that alternative yourself! (+1) I was considering it, but didn't like the generated SQL. Of course nicer looking SQL is not always better :)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I tried here was to create `Conditions` and nest them into one `Expression`. If one of the `Conditions` is met, we get the index of the `Provider` for it.

```
private static Expression NestedExpression(
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> expressions, 
    int startIndex = 0)
{
    var range = expressions.ToList();
    range.RemoveRange(0, startIndex);

    if (range.Count == 0)
        return Expression.Constant(-1);

    return Expression.Condition(
        range[0].Body, 
        Expression.Constant(startIndex), 
        NestedExpression(expressions, ++startIndex));
}
```

Because the `Expressions` still may use different `ParameterExpressions`, we need an `ExpressionVisitor` to rewrite those:

```
private class PredicateRewriterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterExpression;

    public PredicateRewriterVisitor(ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
    {
        _parameterExpression = parameterExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameterExpression;
    }
}
```

For the rewrite we only need to call this method:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Rewrite<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp, 
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
{
    var newExpression = new PredicateRewriterVisitor(parameterExpression).Visit(exp);
    return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)newExpression;
}
```

The query itself and the selection of the `Provider` instances works like this:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "src");
var conditions = Providers.Select(provider => 
    Rewrite(provider.Condition, parameterExpression)
);

var nestedExpression = NestedExpression(conditions);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int>>(nestedExpression, parameterExpression);

var matchInfo = queryable.Select(lambda).Distinct();
var MatchingProviders = Providers.Where((provider, index) => matchInfo.Contains(index));
```

*Note: Another option which isn't really fast as well*

Comment: Also this will not produce correct results in some cases (for instance, only 1 record matching all the filters). So what's the conclusion? I did some tests with 1M records and 10 conditions. The results vary based on conditions, but in general the adaptive queries (that can return result earlier, regardless of the fact that need multiple record reads) perform better. In my tests, Union query is fastest in the average case, then the original (multiple queries), then your answer with `Any`. `Max` based query is the worst (especially if the conditions contain variables).

Comment: You are right. For my use case it still seems like the version with the multiple request from the question is still the fastest of all. followed by your union method. If all else fails I will award the bounty to you tomorrow.

Comment: It's not about the bounty. As I mentioned in the first post, it's an interesting issue and I really wished to get some real improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another view of the problem that has nothing to do with expressions.

Since the main goal is to improve the performance, if the attempts to produce the result with single query don't help, we could try improving the speed by parallelizing the execution of the original multi query solution.

Since it's really a LINQ to Objects query (which internally executes multiple EF queries), theoretically it should be a simple matter of turning it into a [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) query by inserting [`AsParallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413602(v=vs.110).aspx) like this (non working):

```
var matchingProviders = providers
    .AsParallel()
    .Where(provider => queryable.Any(provider.Condition))
    .ToList();
```

However, it turns out that EF `DbContext` is not well suited for multi thread access, and the above simply generates runtime errors. So I had to resort to [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx) using one of the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783538(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads that allows us to supply local state, which I used to allocate several `DbContext` instances during the execution.

The final working code looks like this:

```
var matchingProviders = new List<Provider<TEntity>>();
Parallel.ForEach(providers,
    () => new
    {
        context = new MyDbContext(),
        matchingProviders = new List<Provider<TEntity>>()
    },
    (provider, state, data) =>
    {
        if (data.context.Set<TEntity>().Any(provider.Condition))
            data.matchingProviders.Add(provider);
        return data;
    },
    data =>
    {
        data.context.Dispose();
        if (data.matchingProviders.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (matchingProviders)
                matchingProviders.AddRange(data.matchingProviders);
        }
    }
);
```

If you have a multi core CPU (which is normal nowadays) and a good database server, this should give you the improvement you are seeking for.